# During transaction getting 'Insufficient funds' message from Bitcoin core

Tags: transactions, bitcoin-core, json-rpc

I am trying to make sendbtc transaction using bitcoin rpc call but getting failed message "Insufficient Funds" from bitcoin core.

In addition, once I am trying to make transaction for small amount like below .5 BTC, that transaction successfully done. But for higher value, bitcoin is sending a message "Insufficient funds".

Please suggest me what can I do to make higher value transaction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> we are using the following command `sendfrom "emdad" "19aVGaNfWdZYMgCpMx7tKDXrxeddysddd"`

The account system is deprecated because it has behavior which most people find unexpected, leading to a lot of confusion. Despite the fact that `getbalance "emdad"` returns 10.44 BTC, you do not actually have that much BTC in the wallet, you only have the 0.2692 BTC which `getbalance` and/or `getwalletinfo` showed. That is why you cannot spend more than 0.27 BTC, because you do not have that much.

Note, transactions need to pay a fee too, so you can't send the entire wallet balance as a transaction output, you would only be able to send slightly less than the amount given.